# Autowiring Spring Beans by Interface

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to do hexagonal architecture in my Project.
The module structure looks like this:

[image: My project structure]

[image: IntelliJ error message]

I don't want domain(core) module to be dependant on other modules. It's logic should be exposed through api, hence I want other modules/clients, like a rest module, to be dependant on the API module only.

I want to use RestaurantServiceImpl (from module core) through an interface RestaurantService (from module api). Spring has trouble autowiring a Bean for an interface RestaurantService. Here  is RestaurantServiceImpl which should register correctly as a spring bean:

```
@Service
public class RestaurantServiceImpl implements RestaurantService {

    private final RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;

    @Autowired
    public RestaurantServiceImpl(RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository) {
        this.restaurantRepository = restaurantRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Restaurant> getById(RestaurantId restaurantId) {
        return restaurantRepository.findById(restaurantId);
    }
}
```

restaurant-management-api/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>restaurant-management</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jc</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>restaurant-management-api</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

restaurant-management-core/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>restaurant-management</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jc</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>restaurant-management-core</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <!--________________________INTERNAL________________________-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jc</groupId>
        <artifactId>restaurant-management-api</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
   </dependency>
    <!--________________________SPRING________________________-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
   <!--________________________DATABASE________________________-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

restaurant-management-rest/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>restaurant-management</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jc</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>restaurant-management-rest</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <!--________________________SPRING________________________-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jc</groupId>
        <artifactId>restaurant-management-api</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

restaurant-management/pom.xml

```
<artifactId>restaurant-management</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1</version>
<groupId>com.jc</groupId>
<modules>
    <module>restaurant-management-core</module>
    <module>restaurant-management-api</module>
    <module>restaurant-management-rest</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: Spring has trouble... what does that mean? Where is the error message? And if that red line is what you mean (which is not Spring - it is a compilation error) then just hover your mouse over it and see what it says

Comment: @JAsgarov Added poms and IntelliJ error message. Please let know if I'm lacking some dependencies between modules.

Comment: you need to define spring only once in `restaurant-management/pom.xml`. Child modules will automatically have access to it. Right now you have 3 different spring dependencies all with different spring container. For further reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-multiple-modules

Comment: @JAsgarov thanks for the advice ! I did so but it didn't solve my issue with Beans not being available

Comment: please show your updated `pom.xml`s

Answer (score 0):

Actually I see already what the problem is - you have defined several modules but modules dont see classes defined in another module by default. `RestaurantService` is in another module from `Controller`

You need to add module as a dependency to the other modules pom. Intellij should suggest you to help with that if you just press "Alt+Enter" over the red line.

You might also need to make sure to set up Spring in parent pom to make sure that it spans over all modules.